# encode URL with special characters Javascript

Tags: javascript

firstly just like to say i'm new to Javascript i only really know HTML // CSS. I'm currently using Adfly's API for people to shorten links on my behalf, I wrote a little bit of Javascript to make this work with some html, but I was wondering how to encode the URL before Adfly's API uses it. Due to the amount of special characters in it, it needs to be encoded I know there's multiple ways like:

```
encodeURIcomponent()
encodeURL()
escape()
```

and between them they do the characters I need but none of them do the characters I need individually, also i'm not sure how I would go about implementing them to the javascript I already have.

Here's the code i'm currently using:

Javascript:

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://api.adf.ly/stxt/API Key/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
window.open(url, "_blank");
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="url">
<br>
<button>Go</button>
```

Also not necessary to the question, however would it be possible to open the window in an iframe ?

EDIT:

I managed to get the API generated link to open in iframe however this wasn't my main issue but i'll put code below so people in the future can use it.

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="https://api.adf.ly/stxt/API Key/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
window.open(url, "openlink");
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="url">
<br>
<button>Go</button>
<iframe id="openlink"></iframe>
```

Comment: hmm if you use http you cannot put it into iframe (because it is https) without some setting. I don't know what those are though

Comment: thanks for commenting, i have tried in the past using window.open(url, "iframe") or something i can't remember exactly it was a while ago, but that's not such an issue at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean open a new window, and then make an iframe inside that window? Or do you mean show the URL in an iframe of the current window?

Comment: show iframe in the current window

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: i added it in the question because it was just a little bit more i wanted to know but it wasn't my main question

Answer (score 0):

You should call `encodeURIComponent` to prevent any special characters in the input value from being processed. So it should be:

```
var url="http://api.adf.ly/stxt/API Key/" + enodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("url").value);
```

If you want it to be in an iframe in the popup window, you need to write the HTML that contains the `<iframe>` element into the window.

```
var w = window.open("", "_blank");
w.document.write("<html><body><iframe src='" + url + "'></body></html>");
```

If you meant that you want it to be in an iframe in the current document, you can add this to your HTML:

```
<div id="iframe-container"></div>
```

and use this Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("iframe-container").innerHTML = "<iframe src='" + url + "'>"
```

Comment: i tried the top option and it doesn't generate a link at all it just loads and then hangs, the whole iframe business iv'e got that working just before you posted your solution, my method is above